# Angular MVC routing prefix

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, routes

Application was working fine yesterday, but after modifying a few things here and there, all hell broke loose. My api/xxx calls and root template calls are all being prefixed with the home controller:

```
/Home/api/admin/group/getGroups
/Home/api/admin/role/getRoles
/Home/api/admin/group/getGroups

/Home/directivesHTML/userGrid.html
/Home/directivesHTML/userGrid2.html
/Home/directivesHTML/branchGrid.html
/Home/directivesHTML/feeGrid.html
/Home/directivesHTML/reportGroupGrid.html
/Home/directivesHTML/productGrid.html
/Home/directivesHTML/applicationGrid.html
/Home/Images/loading.gif
```

Config files seem to be fine, dont really know where the issue is. Any idea guys? (thanks.)

```
  $routeProvider
            .when('/home', { templateUrl: '/home/main', controller: 'MainController' })
            .when('/accounts', { templateUrl: '/home/accounts', controller:'accountsController'})
            .when('/reports', { templateUrl: '/home/reports', controller:'reportsController'})
            .when('/login', { templateUrl: '/home/login', controller: 'loginController' })
            .when('/SignIn', { templateUrl: '/home/SignIn', controller: 'loginController' })
            .when('/logout', { templateUrl: '/home/logout', controller: 'loginController' })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
    }])
    .controller('RootController', ['$window', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location',
        function ($window, $rootScope, $scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (e, current, previous) {
            $scope.activeViewPath = $location.path();
       });
    }]);


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RoutConfig
----------
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("Shared/{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: "after modifying a few things here and there" - No doubt you're using version control and can review file changes and see exactly what has changed to cause the error?

Comment: Thanks. It's a project at home, no svn here. In any case, I just added a few methods, removed a controller, and that's pretty much it, meaning, never touched the config files, hence, the reason for this behavior is strange.

Comment: Good stuff. I was of course half joking, but it's never a bad idea to get into the habit of using version control even for home projects. I'd recommend using a Git GUI if you're not familiar with Git already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to be mostly related to my posting from my form's login page. For some reason, it kept the controller "Home" as part of the path from there on. I just replaced the form action, from calling a method in the mvc, to calling a web api method from angular. It works fine now.